# no item with the given id could be found

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script that pdf's and emails Google Form responses to me (based off of TJHouston's script).  It works perfectly but errors if the enduser tries to edit their original response.

The original trigger is onFormSubmit, From Spreadsheet, On Form Submit.  This works great.

I created a second trigger which is onFormSubmit, From Spreadsheet, On edit thinking that was the trigger to prompt another creation of the PDF - but when I click the link to edit my google form responses and then resubmit the form, I get the error "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it." and it references the line
var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)

I also tried the onFormSubmit, From Spreadsheet, On change trigger and got the same results.

```
// Get template from Google Docs and name it
   var docTemplate;
   var docName;
   if (NYcollection == "YES") {docTemplate = "1JRDVjOYxeyl1dXIC115u5W2SQTVgbBMPUERBQ9xfgjo";docName = "Form M";}
   else if (NYcollection == "NO") {docTemplate = "1YGx8wGZyBvfmcfdkTWGQF8XUGlJF7zaYI9ZVO2lYnto";docName = "Form N";}

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
   var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
            .makeCopy(NYfacility +' - '+docName+' '+NYdate +NQE4)
            .getId();

// Open the temporary document
   var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

// Get the document’s body section
   var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template  
   copyBody.replaceText('keyNYname', NYname);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyNYdate', NYdate);
```

The code goes on to replace all my keys and then email the pdf to me.  I'm not understanding why it can get the ID on the initial trigger but not on the edit trigger. Am I using the wrong trigger or should there be additional code in there?

Thanks for any help you can give!!

Comment: The `if` statement checks for either YES or NO.  If neither of those conditions are met, the `docTemplate` variable will be undefined.  Check for undefined.  `if (docTemplate === undefined) {return;};`

Comment: Thanks Sandy, there is always a YES or NO, it's a required dropdown choice.

Comment: Add a `Logger.log('NYcollection: ' + NYcollection);` statement before the `if` check, run the code, then under the VIEW menu, choose LOGS.  What is printed to the log?

Comment: The first time I ran it the log came back with: [15-12-29 10:29:15:601 CST] NYcollection: NO - Complete No Qualifying or Missed Event Form - which is what it should be.  The second time:  [15-12-29 10:31:54:350 CST] NYcollection: 

So it is blanking out the field - even though it is selected as the choice when you go back and do an edit.

Comment: Ok, so, there ***are*** instances in which the the `NYcollection` variable is not either YES or NO.  You probably don't want the code to default to "NO", if there is no value for `NYcollection`.  I'm guessing that your `onEdit()` function is not getting the value that you want.  There's a missing link somewhere between triggering the code, and getting the value to this code.   So, I guess that you have an `onEdit()` function?  If so, can you post that.  Or post whatever code is retrieving the `NYcollection` value.

Comment: I don't have an onEdit() function in my script...  I just created the script you see above, which is onFormSubmit script.  Then I added an additional trigger that I thought would rerun the script when the user resubmits the form (onFormSubmit>From Spreadsheet>On edit).  The user first clicks Google's link to edit their answers (found on the confirmation page after they have already submitted the original) which then takes them back into their original form and they change what they need to change and finally resubmit.

Comment: This is when the onEdit trigger "should" kick in as it sees the spreadsheet updated BUT this is when the NYcollection value gets blanked out - even though it is selected as an option on the edited/resubmitted form.  My final issue is that I can't have NYcollection default to one of the docs because the doc that is chosen must be based on whether they answer YES or NO.  Is there a code where I can tell it to check that NYcollection field again or something along those lines...

Answer (score 0):

Have the code check for the absence of either YES or NO, and if the values you want are not there, use the `getValue()` method of the range class to get the value.

Put this code before the line that assigns the SS ID.

```
if (NYcollection !== "YES" && NYcollection !== "NO") {
  //Get the value
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetWhereValueIs = ss.getSheetByName('YourSheetNameHere');
  var rowOfMyValue = 3;
  var columnOfMyValue = 4;

  var NYcollection = sheetWhereValueIs.getRange(rowOfMyValue, columnOfMyValue).getValue();
};
```